# std::regex and std::tr1::regex compatible?

Tags: c++, regex, visual-c++, c++11, tr1

Is `std::regex` and `std::tr1::regex` totally compatible?

The former is available since C++11.

I want to migrate to `std::regex`.

I use MSVC 2012/2013.

Comment: Yes both are totaly compatible. And If you plan to migrate then just change the namespace from using namespace std::tr1 to using namespace std

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this is the same module, it was just moved from `tr1` to `std`.